# Not able to connect the oracle database to GCP data-stream

Tags: oracle, google-cloud-platform, database-connection, data-stream, google-datastream

I am trying to create a connection profile in GCP data-stream for oracle database. When I try to connect to oracle database, it is showing hostname or port configuration are not correct, even though everything is correct. Can anyone assist me how to resolve this issue, do I need to configure anything for users on oracle side?

I have attached the snapshot of error that I am getting while creating connection profile.

[ERROR SNAPSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZULvT.png)

Answer (score 0):

For your question: "do I need to configure anything for users on oracle side?"

The privileges that you have to grant to the user are the following:

```
GRANT EXECUTE_CATALOG_ROLE TO [gcp_datastream_username];
GRANT CONNECT TO [gcp_datastream_username];
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO [gcp_datastream_username];
GRANT SELECT ANY TRANSACTION TO [gcp_datastream_user];
GRANT SELECT ANY TABLE TO [gcp_datastream_user];
exec rdsadmin.rdsadmin_util.grant_sys_object('V_$DATABASE','[gcp_datastream_user]','SELECT');
exec rdsadmin.rdsadmin_util.grant_sys_object('V_$ARCHIVED_LOG','[gcp_datastream_user]','SELECT');
exec rdsadmin.rdsadmin_util.grant_sys_object('V_$LOGMNR_LOGS','[gcp_datastream_user]','SELECT');
exec rdsadmin.rdsadmin_util.grant_sys_object('V_$LOGMNR_CONTENTS','[gcp_datastream_user]','SELECT');
exec rdsadmin.rdsadmin_util.grant_sys_object('DBMS_LOGMNR','[gcp_datastream_user]','EXECUTE');
exec rdsadmin.rdsadmin_util.grant_sys_object('DBMS_LOGMNR_D','[gcp_datastream_user]','EXECUTE');
```

This is needed ONLY if you are working with Oracle 12c or newer:

```
GRANT LOGMINING TO [gcp_datastream_user];
```